# Change instantiated ViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I created project in Xcode and I removed default "ViewController" class and default view from storyboard. Then I put new view controller in storyboard and table view on it and created new class with name "`StartsController`". At this moment and cannot run my application because it return communicate:

`"-[UITableViewController loadView] instantiated view controller with identifier "UIViewController-BYZ-38-t0r" from storyboard "Main", but didn't get a UITableView".`

How can I choose to my "`StartsController`" to be instantiated controller and then I will run my app correctly?

Comment: After you added a new ViewController, go to identity inspector and check the option "is initial view controller"..I think u must have missed this point

Comment: @Ishika... Unfortunately it's not enough. It still return the same communicate.

Comment: Also make sure to set the new class name for the viewController in the storyboard under the option of custom class

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have tick marked the `is initial ViewController` [image: is initial ViewController]

if you want to do it programmatically, just put this code inside your `AppDelegate.m` in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    StartsController *viewController =  ....;

    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```